# To compute the trace of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A$ be the matrix,
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 3 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$
And the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ by $T(X)=AX$ then what is the trace of $T$?

So I computed the $16 \times 16$ matrix representing  $T$ and it turns out the trace is 48. But can we compute the trace just by looking at $A$?

Comment: Look for kronecker product and vec operator in Wikipedia

Comment: doesn't it 4 times trace of A, why?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose the standard basis for $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ **in the correct order**, the matrix representing $T_A(X) = A \cdot X$ will be a $16 \times 16$ block matrix that consists of four copies of $A$. This works for all $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and hence

$$ \mathrm{trace}(T_A) = n \cdot \mathrm{trace}(A). $$

Similarly, you can relate the characteristic polynomial of $T_A$ to $A$, the eigenspace of $T_A$ to $A$ and so on.