# Finding the trace of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ denote the vector space of $3 \times 3$ matrices. For $A\in V$, let $L_A:V\times V \to V$ be the map defined by $L_A(B)=AB$.

(a) Prove that $L_A$ is a linear transformation for every $A\in V$.

I have already prove this.

(b) Suppose $\text{det}(A)=32$ and the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-4)(x-2)$. What is the trace of $L_A$?

The Jordan form of $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & \\ 1 & 4 & \\ & & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. We can check that $\text{det}(A)=32$. We can see that the trace of $A$ is $10$. How do I calculate the trace of the transformation?

Comment: What’s your definition of trace? Choose a basis for $V$, then calculate the equivalent of the diagonal elements in terms of $A$. It’s possible to express this trace in terms of the trace of $A$.

Comment: The trace of a matrix $A$ is invariant under conjugation: i.e. $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(Q A Q^{-1})$ for all invertible $Q$. Another way to say this is that similar matrices have the same trace. At any rate, the trace of $A$ is the same as the trace of the Jordan normal form, i.e. $4 + 4 + 2 = 10$, not $32$.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek Sorry about that you are right the trace of A is 10

Comment: Can I use the same idea from this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512627/to-compute-the-trace-of-a-linear-transformation ?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Sure, yes, but (as Eric alluded above) really you can probably quite easily start with whatever your definition of the trace of an arbitrary linear map is, and then obtain this result. So if you care to tell us what your definition of trace is we could help more directly. :)

Answer (score -1):

The obvious basis of $V$ are the elementary matrices $E_{ij}$ (definition should be obvious), and the trace is the sum of the projections of $AE_{ij}$ onto $E_{ij}.$

$$(AB)_{kl} = \sum_m a_{km}b_{ml}.$$ The only way the $kl$-th coefficient contains $b_{ij}$ is if $m = i, l = j,$ at which point the term contributes $a_{ki}.$ So, each $E_{ij}$ contributes the $i$-th row sum, so all of them together contribute a multiple of the sum of the entries of $A.$